# Как построить дерево ссылок на javascript?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Подскажите пожалуйста как на javascript реализовать дерево ссылок. Например есть такой массив

```
var array = [
    {id: 1, parent: 0},
    {id: 2, parent: 1},
    {id: 3, parent: 2},
    {id: 4, parent: 1},
    {id: 5, parent: 3},
    {id: 6, parent: 4}
]
```

Как построить меню типа:

```
{
    id: 1,
    parent: 0,
    children: [
        {
            id: 2,
            parent: 1,
            children: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    parent: 2,
                    children: [.....]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = [
    {id: 1, parent: 0},
    {id: 2, parent: 1},
    {id: 3, parent: 2},
    {id: 4, parent: 1},
    {id: 5, parent: 3},
    {id: 6, parent: 4}
]

function makeTree(input) {
  var root = null;
  var byId = {};
  var i;
  
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i].parent == 0)
      root = input[i];
      
    byId[input[i].id] = input[i];
    input[i].children = [];
  }

  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (byId[input[i].parent])
      byId[input[i].parent].children.push(input[i]);
  }

  return root;
}

console.log(makeTree(array));
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, то что надо !